# Using odd/even switch for classNames

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I want each `this.state.title` to align according to a different classname.

I tried using css flex boxes/nth-of-type/nth-child, but it did not play nicely with React.

I'm using `this.state` to get my objects.

## My unsuccessful attempt

```
render: function () {
    let className
    var newVar = !someVar;

 switch(someVar) {
        case odd:
            className= "post-1 line";
            break;
        case even:
            className = "post-2 right-align line";
            break;
    }
    return (
          <article class={I WANT THIS TO FILL FROM SWITCH}>           
              <div class="s-12 l-6 post-image">                   
                 <a href="post-1.html">
                 <img src="/post1.jpg">
                 </a>                
              </div>          
              <div class="s-12 l-5 post-text">
                 <a href="#">
                    <h2>{this.state.title}</h2>
                 </a>
                 <p>Testing           
                 </p>
              </div>

              <div class="s-12 l-1 post-date">
                 <p class="date">28</p>
                 <p class="month">feb</p>
              </div>
           </article>

    );
  }
});
```

Comment: The `switch` isn't wired to any variable...

Comment: I know. I don't know which variable to use there.

Comment: What does your html structure look like surrounding the `div.article` tag(s)?

Comment: I've just added it to my OP

Answer (score 0):

react rewrite class attribute as className,see [react](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html#classname) for more details.

```
    render: function () {
        let className = ['post-2 right-align line', 'post-1 line'][someVar % 2];
        return (
            <article className={className}>
                <div className="s-12 l-6 post-image">
                    <a href="post-1.html">
                        <img src="/post1.jpg"/>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div className="s-12 l-5 post-text">
                    <a href="#">
                        <h2>{this.state.title}</h2>
                    </a>
                    <p>Testing
                    </p>
                </div>

                <div className="s-12 l-1 post-date">
                    <p className="date">28</p>
                    <p className="month">feb</p>
                </div>
            </article>
        );
    }
```

Comment: What should someVar be? It does not make sense to use my objects, as that does not tell me if the item is odd/even when it is presented

Comment: someVar may be pass into as props from parent Component because parent will build it,then the parent know the index and pass into this component as props.

Comment: Yes but using some var (as in my props) does not help as that is not relaible to say if it is an odd or even number.

Comment: why relaible?in parent component you can use a factory in the render method and increment variable in render method to create this component and pass the variable.

Answer (score 0):

The 'someVar' is local variable ? You can try write it in state, Via `this.setState` mutate it for your need.

Comment: someVar is not a local variable. I don't think it makes sense to use a var as that can not reliable tell me anything. This odd/even is purely for the purpose of design.

Answer (score 0):

here is the whole example like this:

```
        class Item extends Component {
            render() {
                let {index, title}=this.props;
                let className = ['post-2 right-align line', 'post-1 line'][index % 2];
                return <li key={index} id={index} className={className}>{title}</li>
            }
        }
        class TodoList extends Component {
            render() {
                let i = 0;
                let itemFactory = (props = {}) => {
                    return <Item key={i} index={i++} {...props}/>
                };
                return (<ul>
                    {this.props.items.map((item) => itemFactory({title: item}))}
                </ul>);
            }
        }
        ReactDOM.render(
            <TodoList items={['first', 'second', 'last']}/>,
            document.getElementById('container')
        );
```